# Does sys.setenv() modify the .Rprofile or .Renviron?

Tags: r

I have been reading about the differences between these files but can't find even in the `Sys.setenv()` documentation which of these files the function is intended to modify?

Comment: `Sys.setenv` does not modify any R files.  It sets an environment variable.  If you have set an environment variable in one of those files or if the variable had previously been set in the operating system and then you set that variable in `Sys.setenv` then it will be overridden with the new value for the rest of the session or until changed.

Answer (score -3):

- You can use `Sys.setenv()` for modifying the `.Rprofile` file.
- You can use `usethis::edit_r_environ()` for modifying the `.Renviron` file.

There's a wealth of information in [this RStudio blog page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf) about the difference between the two.

Comment: You **cannot** use `Sys.setenv()` to modify the `.Rprofile` file. Rather, you edit the [`.Rprofile`](https://rstats.wtf/r-startup.html#rprofile) *by hand*, to add the call `Sys.setenv(ENV_VAR = "value")` and any other **regular R code**. Alternatively, you can add the line `ENV_VAR=value` to the [`.Renviron`](https://rstats.wtf/r-startup.html#renviron) file, along with any other **key-value pairs**. Either of these steps will leave you with the environment variable `ENV_VAR` with the value `"value"` upon startup. Naturally, you can call `Sys.setenv()` within your session, to modify this value.